# Google Sheet IMPORTXML "Imported content is empty"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I want to get the number from this website (https://www.shazam.com/track/488840226/cruel-summer)

But it's return "imported content is empty"

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.shazam.com/track/488840226/cruel-summer","//*[@id='/track/info/488840226']/article[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/p/span/span/em")
```

The number on this website changes every hour, so I want to get the live number on google sheet.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps push all of the rows into an array and take element `array[array.length - 1]`

Comment: Go to the URL and look at Page Source `CTRL+U`, you'll see that the contents of the page is formed via JavaScript so you'll need something like puppeteer that uses chromium browser to scrape the site. That count comes from `https://www.shazam.com/services/count/v2/web/track/488840226`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the website is rendered with JavaScript, so you must use Playwright/Selenium/Puppeteer or similar, as @idchi suggested. But since you are using Google Sheet, and their Rest API is pretty lenient, I offer an alternative to call their API directly in Google Sheets.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(
    IMPORTDATA(
        CONCAT("https://www.shazam.com/services/count/v2/web/track/", REGEXEXTRACT(<URL>, "/track/(\d+)/")),  "ㅤ"
        # specify some random stuff as delimiter so Google doesn't split the data as CSV
    ), """total"":\s*(\d+)"
        # and let's extract the count!
)
```

Comment: I've tried the formula and it works! Thank you so much for the help!